# How to solve datatable warning " Requested Unknown parameter {parameterName} for row[i],column[j]"?

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, datatables

I want to display my DB data using a JQuery Datatable but I keep getting an error as

> DataTables warning: table id=myTable- Requested unknown
>   parameter'productId' for row 0,column 0.

I've already referred the following website http://datatables.net/tn/4 but I still couldn't find any error, I'm using spring mvc and hibernate and here's my code-

contoller code:

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;



import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import model.dao.IProductsDAO;
import model.daoimpl.ProductsDAOImpl;
import model.entity.Products;

@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/manageproducts", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String manageProductPage() {
        return "manageproducts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/insertproducts",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addInserProductsPage(@ModelAttribute("Products")Products p) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.insertProduct(p);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "manageproducts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/listproducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAllProducts(Model model){
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl(); 
        List<Products> products = ip.getProducts(); 
        model.addAttribute ("products",products);
        return "listallproducts";
      }

}
```

jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="//https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectFE/listproducts',
        method: 'get',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data){
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    {'data': 'productId'},
                    {'data': 'productName'},
                    {'data': 'unitPrice'},
                    {'data': 'productDescription'},
                    {'data': 'category'},
                    {'data': 'productQty'}
                ]

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<title>List of Products</title>
</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

so what am I supposed to do here ? please help!!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your `Products` class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  finalData = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectFE/listproducts',
    method: 'get',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data){
        console.log("data length: ", data.length); //to show the length of data
        console.log("data : ", data);  //show the data coming from backend

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      var list = {};
       list.productId = data[i].productId;
       list.productName = data[i].productName;
       list.unitPrice = data[i].unitPrice;
       list.productDescription = data[i].productDescription;
       list.category = data[i].category;
       list.productQty = data[i].productQty;
        finalData.push(list);
        }

        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            data: finalData,
            columns: [
                {'data': 'productId'},
                {'data': 'productName'},
                {'data': 'unitPrice'},
                {'data': 'productDescription'},
                {'data': 'category'},
                {'data': 'productQty'}
            ]

        });
      }
    });
});
```